# Highlight word in div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to implement find and replace functionality in my project. In this functionality there is one find and replace button on the top of `contenteditable` `div`. When user click on this button, a popup window will open and ask for the search word when specify word and press find it will find word in that div only. If any matches were found it will highlight that word. How can I highlight word in `div`.

```html
<div id="test" contenteditable="true">
this is test <font class='classname'> some text test</font>
</div>
```

I want to highlight only the word `test` and nothing else.

Comment: If I follow properly, you have an assignment that has been given personally to you, it's solvable with a simple Google search, you want us to do the work for you anyway, and...what's this..."it's urgent"?  I'm sorry to be so cynical, but this isn't an interesting problem, and you clearly haven't invested yourself to solving it before asking here. -- Could you at least provide code of the HTML you're working with?

Comment: You should use div or span instead of font tags... just fyi.

Comment: @cjstehno - it appears that they aren't using css yet, just javascript and html.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to search through the div to find the word and then put that word into a span, and change the background color of the span.

Edit: I just noticed that you are not using CSS, so you will need to insert a font tag to change the color.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually pretty easy using the [prototype](http://prototypejs.org) library:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <style type="text/css">
            #content span {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Event.observe(window,'load',function(){
                var htm = $('content').innerHTML;
                $('content').innerHTML = htm.sub('my','<span>my</span>');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="content">
            This is the div containing my content.
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

This should get you started so you can implement the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I just stole this from Sphix, the documentation tool:

```
/**
 * highlight a given string on a jquery object by wrapping it in
 * span elements with the given class name.
 */
jQuery.fn.highlightText = function(text, className) {
  function highlight(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
      var val = node.nodeValue;
      var pos = val.toLowerCase().indexOf(text);
      if (pos >= 0 && !jQuery.className.has(node.parentNode, className)) {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.className = className;
        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val.substr(pos, text.length)));
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(span, node.parentNode.insertBefore(
          document.createTextNode(val.substr(pos + text.length)),
          node.nextSibling));
        node.nodeValue = val.substr(0, pos);
      }
    }
    else if (!jQuery(node).is("button, select, textarea")) {
      jQuery.each(node.childNodes, function() {
        highlight(this)
      });
    }
  }
  return this.each(function() {
    highlight(this);
  });
}

/**
 * helper function to hide the search marks again
 */
hideSearchWords : function() {
  $('.sidebar .this-page-menu li.highlight-link').fadeOut(300);
  $('span.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
},

/**
 * highlight the search words provided in the url in the text
 */
highlightSearchWords : function() {
  var params = $.getQueryParameters();
  var terms = (params.highlight) ? params.highlight[0].split(/\s+/) : [];
  if (terms.length) {
    var body = $('div.body');
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $.each(terms, function() {
        body.highlightText(this.toLowerCase(), 'highlight');
      });
    }, 10);
    $('<li class="highlight-link"><a href="javascript:Documentation.' +
      'hideSearchWords()">' + _('Hide Search Matches') + '</a></li>')
        .appendTo($('.sidebar .this-page-menu'));
  }
},
```

So, adding this to a js file in your site, any page with it that receives a highlight GET parameter will search and highlight the word in the page.
You can find a demo of the working code in:

```
http://sphinx.pocoo.org/intro.html?highlight=python
```

**Note**: This code needs jQuery, off course...

Answer (score -1):

To highlight a word you have to select it somehow. One option is to surround the word with a span tag.

```
this is <span class="highlight">test</span> some text test
```

then specify CSS for the highlight class.