# Need to replace font for a particular word

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts, font-family

I want to change the Font family(Arial) to a word 'AAAAA' that was present in a HTML document.  That word can comes many times from DB but I need to replace the font for that single word alone.

I think it will done by JavaScript. Could any one knows how to do it?

Comment: give that element a seperate Id, then change the font.

Comment: Possibility duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411026/highlight-word-in-div-using-javascript & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059682/surrounding-individual-words-inside-html-text-with-span-tags

Comment: Yep. To clarify, find the word, put it in a new element and assign the ID to tha element. Or alternatively, give the element the desired `style.fontFamily`.

Comment: We have some CMS pages, that word will come from that way also. And more over any user comments on the site will also needs to change the font.

Comment: You still display it on a particular element no matter where ever it comes from. So you can get the element with a unique id assigned to it, change the font of it.

Comment: @Sankar, if you look at the questions linked, it will show you how to identify a word and surround it with a span tag at client side. Then you can change the fontfamily, color and do what every stying you want by applying css class the element.

Comment: Reedited my answer. Take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say we need Georgia

```
  .geo{
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:19px;
  }
```

### *[demo](http://jsbin.com/arupaj/3/edit)*

```
var $els = $('body *'); // iterate through all elements // or define specific for performance.

$els.each(function(){ 
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/AAAAA/g, '<span class="geo">AAAAA</span>')); 
});
```

IF the `<span>` could give you problems (as commonly used through the DOM) ... I'd suggest to use `<font>` : `<font class="geo">AAAAA</font>`

Answer (score 2):

```
$.fn.changeWord = function (str, className) {
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "gi");
    return this.each(function () {
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(matched) {
            return "<span class='" + className + "'>" + matched + "</span>";
        });
    });
};
```

Call it

```
$('#myDiv').changeWord('specialWord', 'sw');
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9BSn/3/)

**Update:** [**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/x9BSn/2/)

Comment: it is working but it have some problem. tr with the below code
<div id="myDiv">
    specialWord <a href="http://www.google.com/specialWord">specialWord</a> 
</div>​

Comment: I face the same issue in JQuery -1.7.1.

Comment: Heera that issue was not yet fixed. Check the source code of the below below link. It replace the content in the link also. 

http://fiddle.jshell.net/x9BSn/2/show/

Comment: You are trying to change the link text and that was not your question and so answer has given depending on your question. http://jsfiddle.net/x9BSn/8/

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //$('body').replaceWith( $('<div></div>').append($(body).clone()).html().replace(/AAAA/g, '<span style="font-family: Arial; color:red;">AAAA</span>');


            //Or


            // global and case sensitive search in string
            $('#replaceTest2').replaceWith($('<div></div>').append($('#replaceTest2').clone()).html().replace(/AAAA/g, '<span style="font-family: Arial; color:red;">AAAA</span>'));
            // global and case insensitive search in string
            $('#replaceTest3').replaceWith($('<div></div>').append($('#replaceTest3').clone()).html().replace(/AAAA/gi, '<span style="font-family: Arial; color:red;">AAAA</span>'));
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Batang;
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Original Text
    </h1>
    <div id="replaceTest1">
        Hi.. testing <span style="font-family: Ebrima;">test aaaa</span>
        <div>
            <span style="font-family: Bookshelf Symbol 7; font-style: normal;">rreee AAAA </span>
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>
        Original Text Replace ( global and case sensitive search in string )
    </h1>
    <div id="replaceTest2">
        Hi.. testing <span style="font-family: Ebrima;">test aaaa</span>
        <div>
            <span style="font-family: Bookshelf Symbol 7; font-style: normal;">rreee AAAA </span>
            test
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>
        Original Text Replace ( global and case insensitive search in string )
    </h1>
    <div id="replaceTest3">
        Hi.. testing <span style="font-family: Ebrima;">test aaaa</span>
        <div>
            <span style="font-family: Bookshelf Symbol 7; font-style: normal;">rreee AAAA </span>
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```