# Variable inside a String inside a String

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I'm running into a little problem when I try to put a variable inside a string that's already inside a string. Basically, I'm trying to change the color of a specific word with a color variable (a string, e.g. "#FF0"). That's what the replace function looks like:

```
$('#textWithTheWord').replaceWith($('<div></div>').append($('#textWithTheWord').clone()).html().replace(word, '<span style="color:red;">' + word + '</span>'));
```

Note that I want to replace the "red" in `'<span style="color:red;">'` with that variable.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: if I understand correctly, `#textWithTheWord` is an `element` that contains a `span` with has an inline `style` attribute that sets the `color`. You then want to modify the `color` value for that `span` element. Is that right? If that's the case, is there any reason you want to do this by manipulating strings?

Comment: @plalx Yes, so far, you're correct. I tried to change the color of a specific word and the only solution I found for that was here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328281/need-to-replace-font-for-a-particular-word).

Comment: I have posted an answer to your problem, I hope it helps. Best luck! ;)

Comment: It surely helped making my code look a little "smarter"! :)
But I still have the color-variable, that's able to change, and I'm wodering, how to change the color.

Comment: Check out `wrap` for the tricky thing you're doing with the `div`: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: @felixfritz, do you mean that the word is already wrapped in a span and you are trying to change it's color?

Comment: @felixfritz, I updated my answer with more explanations and a fiddle that shows an implementation of the concept I was explaining yesterday. It is definitely overkill for what you wanted, but I had some fun hehe... and you will be able to do whatever you want with the text.

Comment: @felixfritz, For an easier solution, just try to re-explain your question differently so that I understand exactly what you need, not more, not less.

Comment: @plalx Thank you so much for your help, you seem to have put in a lot of effort into it. It took me some time to understand the coding, but it's perfectly what I need! Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @felixfritz, I'm glad I could help! It's good that you took time to understand how things are done, this way you can craft a solution specific for your needs. Cheers! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution would be to simply replace the `innerHTML` property of your element by a new html string that would have wrapped the words in a `span`. However, it's not a very flexible solution, since by replacing the `innerHTML` property, all the elements would be renewed and that might give unexpected results, unless you target elements that only holds text nodes.

Lets suppose the `body` contains this text:

```
this is some text and I want to replace the word cool
```

You could have:

```
var $body = $(document.body);

$body.html($body.html().replace(/\b(cool)\b/g, '<span style="color: red;">$1</span>'));
```

Here the `/\b(cool)\b/g` regex will match every *cool* words and create a capturing group on them, allowing us to reference it in the replacement expression as `$1`.

However, a most advanced solution could probably be implemented like:

- Loop over text nodes not contained within a `span` that has a `data-styled-text` attribute. (you could check the `textNode.parentNode` property)
- Sourround the words that you want by a `<span data-styled-text>` tag. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/Text.splitText
- Query all the `<span data-styled-text>` elements and do whatever manipulation you want with them.

I have toyed around with that concept and I have create a fiddle for you that shows how you could manipulate text in any ways you want using a `regex` to target specific text. I have created 2 main functions `wrapText` and `styleText` that will allow you to do whatever you want with text on the page. It could be further optimzed, but you will get the idea.

**Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/scarsick/tX4Ge/1/**

The following function allows you to wrap any text in a text node.

```
function wrapText(textNode, textRx, wrapFn) {
    var global = textRx.global,
        wrapEl,
        result, 
        rightTextNode,
        matchedText,
        index;

    while (result = textRx.exec(textNode.nodeValue)) {
        rightTextNode = textNode.splitText(index = result.index);
        rightTextNode.nodeValue = rightTextNode.nodeValue.substring((matchedText = result[0]).length);
        wrapEl = wrapFn(matchedText, index);
        wrapEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(matchedText));
        rightTextNode.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapEl, rightTextNode);

        if (!global) {
            break;
        }

        textNode = rightTextNode;
        textRx.lastIndex = 0;
    }    
}
```

The following function allow you to style any text contained within an element.

```
function styleText(el, textRx, styleFn) {
    var wrapEl = document.createElement('span'),
        slice = [].slice;

    wrapEl.setAttribute('data-styled-text', 'true');

    styleText = function(el, textRx, styleFn) {
        var childNodes = slice.call(el.childNodes, 0),
            i = 0,
            len = childNodes.length,
            node;

        for (; i < len; i++) {
            node = childNodes[i];

            switch (node.nodeType) {
                case 3:
                     if (!node.parentNode.getAttribute('data-styled-text')) {
                         wrapText(node, textRx, function (text, index) {
                             var el = wrapEl.cloneNode();

                             styleFn(el, text, index);

                             return el;
                         });

                         continue;
                    }

                    styleFn(node.parentNode);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    styleText(node, textRx, styleFn);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    styleText(el, textRx, styleFn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of that code exists only to change the colour of the text in the element, you can simplify it greatly like so:

```
var color = "#ff8877";
$('#textWithTheWord').css('color', color);
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

There's no need to play about with the DOM or string concatenation to change attributes or styling of an element. jQuery will likely have a function that does what you want already.