# Find occurrences -not yet enclosed by A tags- and surround by A tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I am trying to make good use of HTML *definition lists*, to serve as a glossary with tooltips. Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pCxcd/1/) for the intended result (at the bottom).

If parts of the text in an article match the terms in the definition list, a tooltip bubble is shown with the matching definition. This is done by a surrounding A-tag. So far so good.

Now the question is how to parse the article so that all the parts that can be found in the glossary will get automatically surrounded by A-tags. The terms can be for instance:

- group
- social group
- group behavior
- research

The parsing has to be 'greedy' so it parses the longest definition first.

```
var arr = []; /* Array of terms, sorted by length */
$('#glossary dt').each( function() { arr.push($(this).text()); });
arr.sort(function(a,b) { return b.length - a.length; });
```

Next it has to surround occurrences of the first array-item in #article.html by A-tags, unless they are already within A-tags. Also this should be case-insensitive.

```
/* don't know how to approach this */
```

Finally move to the next array item and repeat.

```
/* ok, i can figure the loop out myself */
```

My problem is with checking if a certain string is already within A-tags and also with placing A-tags around a part of text. Replace should be avoided to keep the upper/lowercase the same. Check the JSfiddle for the intended result.

---

edit: Building on the solution of plalx below, I came up the following code:

```
/*
This script matches text strings in an article with terms in a defintion list (DL);
the DL acts as a glossary. The text strings are wrapped in '<span>' tags,
with the 'title' attribute containing the definition. This allows for easy custom tooltips.

- This script is 'greedy' the longest terms are matched first;
- This script preserves capitalization and escapes HTML in the definitions
 */
var $article = $('#container-inhoud');
var $terms = $('#glossary dt');
//clone to avoid multiple DOM reflows
var $clone = $article.clone();

//create a regex that matches all glossary terms (not case-sensitive), sorted by length
var rx = new RegExp('\\b(' + $terms.map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get().sort(function (term1, term2) {
                    return term2.length - term1.length;
                }).join('|') + ')\\b', 'ig');


var entityMap = {
    "&": "&amp;",
    "<": "&lt;",
    ">": "&gt;",
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#39;',
    "/": '&#x2F;'
};

function escapeHtml(string) {
    return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (s) {
        return entityMap[s];
    });
}

//wrap any text string that corresponds with a definition term in a 'span' tag
//the title contains the connected definition.
function replacer(match){
        var definition = $terms.filter(function() {
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase() == match.toLowerCase();
        }).next('dd').text();
        definition = escapeHtml(definition);
        return '<span class="tooltip" title="' + definition + '">' + match + '</span>';
}

//call the replace function for every regex match
$clone.html($clone.html().replace(rx , replacer));

//unwrap the terms in the glossary section (to avoid tooltips within the glossary itself)
//only needed if the #glossary is within the #article container, otherwise delete the next line.
$clone.find('#glossary .tooltip').contents().unwrap();

$article.replaceWith($clone);
```

The following code displays the tooltips.

```
/*
 This script displays a tooltip for every 'span' with class 'tooltip'.
 The 'title' attribute will be displayed as the tooltip.
 The tooltip is displayed directly above and in line with the left side of the element.
 Any offsetting is done by manipulation the 'left' and 'top' attributes in the CSS.
 */
$("span.tooltip").hover(
        function () {
            var bubble = $("#bubble");
            bubble.text($(this).attr('title'));
            var ypos = $(this).offset().top - bubble.height();
            var xpos = $(this).offset().left;
            bubble.css({"left":xpos+"px","top":ypos+"px"});
            bubble.show();
        },
        function () {
            $("#bubble").hide();
        }
);
```

I used to following CSS to format the tooltip bubble:

```
#bubble{
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            color: #ee6c31;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
            position:absolute;
            z-index:200;
            padding:5px 8px;
            margin: -15px 5px 5px -10px;
            display:none;
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958020/variable-inside-a-string-inside-a-string/15959797#15959797

Comment: Thanks, trying to wrap my head around that now.

Comment: You may use the easy regex replacement solution described in the answer if the parent element of the node that hold's the article's content doesn't contain any other elements with behaviour directly attached to them. If the behaviour is attached using delegation, there shouldn't be issues caused by replacing the `innerHTML` value of the article's container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I crafted a little solution for you. I think this is what you want:

HTML SAMPLE:

```
<div id="glossary">
    <dt>test</dt>
    <dt>Testing</dt>
    <dt>something</dt>
    <dt>some other thing</dt>
    <dt>long test</dt>
</div>

<div id="article">
    this is a test, to see if Testing will correctly be wrapped by something, or some other thing.
    This <a data-glossary-term href="#test">test</a> should not be wrapped again however, <span>something</span> should!
    Very long test should also be wrapped first.
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var $article = $('#article'),
        //clone to avoid multiple DOM reflows
        $clone = $article.clone(),
        //create a regex that matches all glossary terms (not case-sensitive)
        rx = new RegExp('\\b(' + $('#glossary dt').map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get().sort(function (term1, term2) {
            return term2.length - term1.length;
        }).join('|') + ')\\b', 'ig');

    //unwrap previously wrapped glossary terms to avoid issues
    //this would not be needed if your initial markup doesn't have terms wrapped already
    $clone.find('[data-glossary-term]').each(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith(this.childNodes);
    });

    //wrap terms in the 'a' tag
    $clone.html($clone.html().replace(rx, '<a data-glossary-term="$1" href="#$1">$1</a>'));

    $article.replaceWith($clone);
});
```

Comment: Still have to check that one, but it has so much beauty in it. As you probably gather, I am new to javascript, but you are making it look good.

Comment: Works like I charm, but I have to read up on RegEx to totally get it. Some stuff I have to work on: the problem with 'replace' is that it will not respect original capitalization. Imagine that a sentence starts with: 'Something' > this would get replaced by 'something'. Also now the A tags will replace previous A tags. Even if the original A tags span a longer bit of text, which includes a term. Not a problem for me, but it would be nice to make the behavior optional. Thx again for investing the effort.

Comment: @snirp Basically, when you are modifying DOM elements, it causes [DOM reflows](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow?hl=fr) Here I am cloning the initial node to work with the element outside of the document flow to avoid multiple reflows when I remove initial data glossary terms and then change the innerHTML propety of the element. If you do not have to remove initial glossary terms, you do not have to work with a clone since the only operation that will be performed is changing the `innerHTML` prperty, causing a single reflow.

Comment: @snirp, Are you sure that it doesn't preserve capitalization? It really should since I am using a reference to the capturing group in the replace pattern. It works for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zMEfE/). Have a look at the *Testing* word. As for the initial tags, I will have a look at a solution later, not enough time this morning ;)

Comment: I see you did that (an now I know why). Any specific reason you defined the variable as '$clone' (with the jQuery prefix) instead of 'clone'? edit: You are right about the capitalization. My bad.

Comment: @snirp, I am using the `$` prefix to clearly identity that the variable holds a reference to a jQuery object. It's a pretty common naming convention ;) As for the initially wrapped glossary terms, I tought about it and why would a group of words be already wrapped together in a `data-glossary-term` element if that group of word isin't an entry in the glossary?

Comment: My thinking was that any part of the text could already be in A-tags for other reasons (external reference). But now I doubt whether I even **should** use A, or maybe just go with SPAN. Technically it would not be much different and I could preserve A-tags. As long as they do not partially overlap. Sorry about this being a work in progress.

Comment: I updated the post with details of my implementation. Thank you for doing the heavy lifting. I might dedicate a blog entry to this. How should I credit you for your contribution?

Comment: @snirp I'm glad my solution could help you build something adapted to your needs! Perhaps instead of cloning, you could also remove the element from the document and re-insert it at the same place once you finish to manipulate it, but you dont have to if you have good peformances. That's very kind of you, you can perhaps put a reference to me somewhere **Alexandre Potvin Latreille (plalx)** with a link to my stack profile.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of collecting the dt text into the array, collect the dom items themselves, then create a function like this:

```
function add_tags(td) {
    var dd = td.next(),
        q = td.text()
        txt = dd.text().replace(q, '<a href="#">'+q+'</a>');

    dd.html(txt);
};
```

And loop it. You'd probably want to add some check function to see if there are already any a-tags surrounding your word, but that's a good place to start

Comment: I think I need to have the array, because I need it sorted by length first. 
 
As I said, a simple replace() might not work with capitals. For instance, I want "Research" to match the term "research", but not replaced by lowercase.
 
In your example, the check function for the A tag should go in the second argument of the replace() method, right?

Comment: I didn't say drop the array completely I said don't build an array for the text inside the td but rather of the td themselves. Then sort it according to the length of the text and loop my function. It's just a general example, not a full solution. I tried showing you what you didn't know how to approch

Comment: Ok, I get you. I seemed to have that part working, though. Maybe my solution was sub-optimal there.

Comment: No no... I was just thinking you ment to do something else (search the keyword for each td in the dd), but your current fiddle clears things up a bit. I think plalx gave you a more complete solution