# Regex - Replace text in HTML string when not contained within HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, vb.net

I'm hoping someone can help with this little problem.

I've have a HTML string, a simplified example of which is shown below, which I need to find and replace text within. But only if that text doesn't appear within HTML tags i.e. "<" and ">".

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
In this text I'd like to replace the word "in" with another piece of text instead.
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

For example I'd like to replace the word "in" with the span string below resulting in the full HTML below that.

```
<span class="highlight">in</span>


<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<span class="highlight">In</span> this text I'd like to replace the word "<span class="highlight">in</span>" with another piece of text <span class="highlight">in</span>stead.
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The reason I only want the text replacing which appears between ">" and "<" is becasue I don't want the HTML to break by replacing the word "in" in the "cellspacing" and "cellpadding" attributes.

If this can't be solved using regex I'm also open to doing it in VB.NET, Javascript or JQuery.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

SOLVED!

Thanks to MiddleCSharp for your wisdom

```
Dim rgx As New Regex(String.Format("\b{0}\b", SearchText, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) 
ltrPageCopy.Text = rgx.Replace(HTMLText, String.Format("<span class=""highlight"">{0}</span>", SearchText))
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958020/variable-inside-a-string-inside-a-string/15959797#15959797

Comment: This seems to involve parsing HTML to get to the string. Use the built–in parser for that, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) about using a regular expression to parse HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace only the word `in` excluding words that contain "in", use:

```
\bin\b
```

Example, http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?370qr

To replace anything inside `><` tags no matter what type of tag it is, try this

Find:

`(<.*?>)(.*?)(</.*?>)`

Replace:

$1`YOUR_TEXT`$3

Where `YOUR_TEXT` is what you want to change the content inside `><` to.

Here's the demo http://regexr.com?370r1

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. It can be any word not just the word "in", it's taken from user's search term. I'm giving "in" as the example as this breaks the HTML quite badly in this instance. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks MiddleCSharp! You initial response got me there. 
Here's my final code.
    Dim rgx As New Regex(String.Format("\b{0}\b", SearchText, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    ltrPageCopy.Text = rgx.Replace(HTMLText, String.Format("<span class=""highlight"">{0}</span>", SearchText))

Comment: `\b` also matches hyhphen (-), so the pattern will match "in" in "built-in". It might be better to use something like /(^|\s)in(\s|$)/.

Comment: @user2943355 Not a problem, I've added back the initial response to the answer.