# what is the non-jquery equivalent (plain javascript) of this algorithm?

Tags: javascript, dom

The answer [jQuery - wrap all unwrapped text in p tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836633/jquery-wrap-all-unwrapped-text-in-p-tags) gives a jquery solution that wraps all text nodes with an html tag. I am wondering how to do it without jquery (if possible).

Comment: Have you tried it yet? Where are you stuck? Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958020/variable-inside-a-string-inside-a-string/15959797#15959797

Comment: how is this offtopic, it's about javascript and asking a javascript question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/reWXX/14/

```
var textnodes = getTextNodesIn(document.getElementById('demo'));

for(var i=0; i < textnodes.length; i++){

    if (textnodes[i].parentElement.id === 'demo') { //    This is redundant 

        var newNode = document.createElement('p');
            newNode.textContent =  textnodes[i].nodeValue;

        textnodes[i].parentNode.replaceChild(newNode,  textnodes[i]);
    }
}
```

This is in plain JavaScript. However if Markasoftware works, IMHO that would be the proper way to do it, with a TreeWalker.

Comment: what is `getTextNodesIn`?

Comment: Gets text nodes function. I thought its too big to post it here. Please look in the http://jsfiddle.net/reWXX/14/. I've just rewrite what I got.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```
var walker=document.createTreeWalker(document.body,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
while(walker.nextNode()){
    var newNode=document.createNode('p');
    newNode.textConTent=walker.currentNode.textContent;
    walker.currentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(newNode,walker.currentNode);
}
```

I haven't tested it yet and I've never used a `treeWalker` before, but I think this should work fine. I'm not sure, however, if the while loop MIGHT skip the first text node in the document. You'll just have to try.