# Highlight word based on the word count in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

If I have the following string: `This is another song you should listen to`
I was trying to write a function to only highlight the word based on the word count.  For example, I want to highlight the 4th word using a method like: `highlightWord(originalString,nthWord)`.  And the returned string would be:

`This is another <span class=\"highlighted\">song</span> you should listen to`

I tried using a `highlightMatch` function that I wrote, one by passing a search string `(regexMatch = "is")`, but the problem is that it highlights the is in `This` instead of `is`:

```
function highlightMatch(originalValue,regexMatch) {
    var tempInnerHTML = stripTags(originalValue);
    originalValue.innerHTML = tempInnerHTML.replace(regexMatch,'<span class="highlighted">'+regexMatch+'</span>');
}
```

I also tried using this highlightNthWord method:

```
function highlightNthWord(string,n) {
    var m = string.match(new RegExp('^(?:\\w+\\W+){' + n + '}(\\w+)'));
    return m && '<b>'+m[1]+'</b>';
}
```

But this one just returns only the nth word highlighted, not the whole sentence with the nth word highlighted.
I'm hoping to stick with javascript only (no jquery).

Comment: [Use `split()` & `join()`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/wo6u1z82/1/)

Comment: Definitely overkill, but I had answered a similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958020/variable-inside-a-string-inside-a-string/15959797#15959797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string be space and then build the string back:

```js
function highlightNthWord(string,n) {
  var m = string.split(new RegExp(/\s+/));
  return m.splice(0, n-1).join(" ") + (' <b>'+m.splice(0, 1)+'</b> ') + m.join(" ");
}
console.log(highlightNthWord('This is another song you should listen to', 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function highlightMatch(originalValue, matchString) {
    var re = new RegExp(matchString, "igm");
    var replace = '<span class="highlighted">'+matchString+'</span>';
    return originalValue.replace(re ,replace);
}
```